# Mapnik zoom_to_box for shape

Tags: python, shapefile, mapnik, zoom

I have used the code from Mapnik python tutorial. Now I want to use zoom_to_box to zoom to certain extent. I want to zoom to Box2d(-180.0, 0.0, 0.0, 90.0), however, after appied zoom_to_box, I saw the map envelope is Box2d(-180.0,-45.0,0.0,135.0), so what do I miss here?

The testing shapefile can be downloaded here: [shapefile](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/data/110m-admin-0-countries.zip)

Here below my code:

```
import mapnik
m = mapnik.Map(256,256)
m.background = mapnik.Color('steelblue')
s = mapnik.Style()
r = mapnik.Rule()
polygon_symbolizer = mapnik.PolygonSymbolizer(mapnik.Color('#f2eff9'))
r.symbols.append(polygon_symbolizer)
line_symbolizer = mapnik.LineSymbolizer(mapnik.Color('rgb(50%,50%,50%)'),0.1)
r.symbols.append(line_symbolizer)
s.rules.append(r)
m.append_style('My Style',s)
ds = mapnik.Shapefile(file='ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp')
print ds.envelope()
layer = mapnik.Layer('world')
layer.datasource = ds
layer.styles.append('My Style')
m.layers.append(layer)
print m.envelope(), layer.envelope()
m.zoom_all()
print m.envelope(), m.scale()
bbox = mapnik.Box2d(-180.0, 0.0, 0.0, 90.0)  # 00
m.zoom_to_box(bbox)
print m.envelope(), m.scale()
mapnik.render_to_file(m,'world00.png', 'png#')
print "rendered image to 'world.png'"
```

Comment: can anybody help?

Comment: I came by your question when searching for a similar problem. Probably too late, but I found this page and thought it might be helpful to others: https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/Aspect-Fix-Mode I set aspect_fix_mode to `map.aspect_fix_mode = mapnik.aspect_fix_mode.RESPECT`, and mapnik respected my bbox!

Answer (score 2):

kaveh is probably right. The `zoom_to_box()`method sets the extent and then call the `fixAspectRatio()`method. More details here: https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/blob/7931295d3322b7cc57f820d7e2db6449d791159f/src/map.cpp#L581

Depending on the `aspect_fix_mode` that you have picked, it will readjust the extent. If you don't want it to modify your extent, you can set the `aspect_fix_mode`to `RESPECT`and the following code will be executed at the beginning of the `fixAspectRatio()`method:

```
if (aspectFixMode_ == RESPECT) return;
```

leaving your extent unchanged.